# WCF with Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have read a few articles in how to connect to a WCF service in a VB .Net application but nothing is 100% concrete in understanding whats happening and under what event if any.

I have a service created in C# which has the following method:

```
    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        var c = myDataContext.Customers.ToList();
        return c;
    }
```

So we know it returns a List of Customers. Now in a Windows Phone Application (VB .Net project) i try and create an instance of the service and iterate through the Customer list:

```
Dim CustService As New CService.CustomerClient

For Each i In CustService.GetCustomers

Next
```

Now this returns the error *Expression doesnt produce a value*

I know this is a List and it returns some value (Web service has also been tested by other means). Reading a dozen articles which seem to be in C# it seems i have to have something inside an event but really struggling to work this out to see what im doing wrong.

Can anyone guide me or point me to something that would help me overcome the above issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WCF the methods that return values use an asynchronous callback. Consider this:

On WCF:

```
<OperationalContract>
Public Function GetCustomers() As List(Of Customer)
  Using db As New DatabaseContext
    Return db.Customers.ToList
  End Using
End Function
```

Method on service:

```
Private customers As List(Of CService.Customer)
Private Sub GetCustomers()
 Dim cs As New CService.CustomerClient
 Addhandler cs.GetCustomersCompleted, AddressOf CustomersCompleted
 cs.GetCustomersAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub CustomersCompleted(sender As Object, e As GetCustomersEventArgs)
  customers = e.Result
End If
```

I am not sure what else would be diff for Windows Phone 8.

Comment: Following the above, i had to follow the instructions found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580(v=vs.105).aspx in order to get it fully working